# Regular expression replace string in Python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to replace a string in Python 3 using regex. I need the string in `s1` to be completely replaced with an empty string.

```
s1 = "/*  123  */"  # Pattern /*  n  */ where n can be any integer  
s2 = re.sub(r'/*\s*\d+\s*/',"",s1)
print(s2)
```

Output(Actual) - `/*  123  */`  # nothing happens

Output (Expected) - `BLANK`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*` is a meta character, you need to escape it if you want to match a literal `*` character. You are also missing the literal `*` character just before the closing `/`:

```
s2 = re.sub(r'/\*\s*\d+\s*\*/', "", s1)
```

Your code was matching zero or more `/` characters, and zero or more `\s` spaces, but not any of the literal `*` characters at the start and end of the comment.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> s1 = "/*  123  */"
>>> re.sub(r'/\*\s*\d+\s*\*/', "", s1)
''
```

Answer (score 0):

\S+ all no space characters,\s+ space.

```
[31]: re.sub(r'\S+|\s+', "", s1)
Out[31]: ''
```